# Task Scheduler Error (0x1)?

Tags: batch-file, curl, scheduled-tasks

I created batch file with curl script for my Task Scheduler in windows. For some reason I'm keep getting error 0x1 after my script runs in scheduler. Here is my batch file script:

```
dir C:\curl.exe
for %%# in ("E:\One\Two\*.txt") do  curl.exe -T "%%~f#" -u UserName:Password ftp://ftp.test.com/Hello/%%~nx#
```

If anyone can tell me what is wrong with my script or how I should create call in task scheduler.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of the first line (`dir C:\curl.exe`)?

Comment: To point to directory where my curl.exe is stored. I'm not sure if I need that or not?

Comment: That's not what `dir` does. `dir` is a directory listing, like `ls` on *nix hosts. `cd` changes directories. And if the location of curl is part of your %path% variable, you don't need that step at all.

Comment: I tried to remove that first line of code but my batch file still does not work.

Comment: Removing it isn't enough. Add the full path to `curl.exe` like this: `for....do c:\curl.exe .....`.